# To test whether gmail account exists or not

Tags: objective-c

I want to login using gmail in my app is it possible to test whether the given gmail a/c exists or not programmatically in objective c.

Answer (score 3):

Run these commands:

```
telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25
ehlo
mail from: <me@example.com> //can be any made up email
rcpt to: <somenonexistinguser@gmail.com> //the email of the user you want to check
```

Please note you must include the greater and less than or equal to signs.

If you get OK followed by a string returned, the email is valid. Anything else, and an error will have been returned (ergo, the email is invalid).

Comment: Good answer. OP, bear in mind that this should work for one address, but if you test multiple addresses in quick succession, you'd be liable to be blocked by GMail.

Comment: i didn't get where i need to run these commands @jacktheripper.

Comment: Run them in Terminal if you're on a mac. These commands should be universal to the command prompt of any UNIX system.

Comment: But i want to test this through my iphone app not on mac

Comment: There should be a telnet library available in iOS.